# How to remove a "branch" in repository after a git rebase on my local machine

Tags: git, merge, repository, branch, git-branch

I would like to delete a branch on my local repository. The problem is that it doesn't appear to be one.

I tried to merge from my branch called "Website" to master and i made a mistake by doing.

```
git rebase website
```

and now I would like to delete the new branch which is actually not one. When I want to see on which branch it is writen "No branch, rebasing master"

[image: Screenshot from my terminal]

Basically, what i want is to delete this "branch".

Comment: Next time, please take a moment to read the formatting help, rather than hammering the keyboard and hoping for the best.

Comment: It is understood.

Comment: I think that's just because you're in the middle of your rebase. Abort it or finish it and this temporary state will disappear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to do `git branch -D name_branch`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not on a branch, so there is nothing to delete.

[As Phillipe noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40204924/how-to-remove-a-branch-in-repository-after-a-git-rebase-on-my-local-machine#comment67674612_40204924), you are in the middle of a rebase that had to pause, due (no doubt) to conflicts.  Git currently expects you to fix the conflicts and resume the rebase, or abort the rebase.  If your Git is not too ancient, simply running:

```
git status
```

will give you some instructions on fixing-and-resuming.  Meanwhile:

```
git rebase --abort
```

will terminate the stopped-to-get-help rebase and put things back the way they were before you attempted the rebase.